# Traversing through table headers in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qky4zx2o/

What I'm trying to achieve is that each `New Task` button must have an index attribute that corresponds to the column it is under.

Columns `1, 4.1, 4.2, 5` are the columns to be considered for this case. All column headers in `columnHeaders` are not fixed however, which makes it trickier.

For `New Task` button #1 in `row rl`, how can I assign the id of `column 1` to it?

For `New Task` button #2 in `row rl`, how can I assign the id of `column 4.1` to it? So on and so forth. In `columnHeaders`, the columns in `level 1` with children are disregarded, and their children are the ones considered.

I basically build two separate tables and just align them with one another, thus the `.has_width` for the `<th>` with `rowspan > 0` and in `level 2`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML.

Comment: this looks like a PHP-related question?

Comment: @Hopeless pretty much, yes. I just haven't figured out yet how to do it, whether control the structure by PHP or by jQuery.

Comment: you should try improving the question to make it clearer. Currently, for the specific figurative example you provided, I can guess out what the problem is and what you want. But it's just guessing. There are more unclear points here: Do you have just 1 table here? (and it has 2 groups of headers named as `Table 1` and `Table 2`? If so, you already have the first group of headers indexed and the requirement is just indexing the second? Then we need to start querying from the second headers (meaning to collect all headers `Table 2`, but in your code you start from collecting all `.has_width`)...

Comment: btw, to help solving this better, try focusing on a simple demo to simulate your situation. Once we solve that simple demo, you can solve your real problem yourself easily. That's how to ask in SO. Sometimes you don't need to show your original problem, instead you take some effort yourself first to find out the guts of issue you have, simplify it before asking in here.

Comment: @Hopeless hmm, as much as i want to show the php code for how the table is created I think it'll add more confusion than help, okay I'll try to simplify the question further

Comment: In fact you have 2 approaches here: Solving at the server side using PHP and Solving at the client side using javascript & jQuery. But looks like you want to go for the second approach. So just show HTML code (the generated one by the PHP script, also only the HTML code of table should be involved here). You can make a simple demo (using codepen, jsfiddle.net, ...). Many users made faimiliar with such online tools to help showing and solving HTML-related problems easily (even right in SO editor, there is a <code> block - but really I don't like this feature of SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, the natural approach is firstly creating an array (more likely a dictionary) to lookup for the mapped `data-column-index`. By using that array, you can just lookup the corresponding index of the `td` element and access the calculated info there.

The first phase is initialize such an array, something like this:

```
var indexInfo = [];
$("#columnHeaders > tbody > tr").first().find("th:gt(0)").each(function(i,e){
    //obtain colspan of the current th elementv
    var csa = $(this).attr("colspan");
    //obtain the rowspan of the current th element
    var rsa = $(this).attr("rowspan");
    var cs = csa == undefined ? 1 : parseInt(csa);
    var rs = rsa == undefined ? 1 : parseInt(rsa);
    //obtain the data-column-index of the current th element
    var cia = $(this).data("column-index");
    var ci = cia == undefined ? -1 : parseInt(cia);
    var startIndex = indexInfo.length;  
    var endIndex = startIndex + cs;
    //initializing the indexInfo array
    for(var k = startIndex; k < endIndex; k++){
      indexInfo[k] = { rowSpan : rs, colIndex : ci};
    }
});
```

The next phase is update the array so that it contains only desired info. We need to loop through all remaining header rows to update this array, something like this:

```
$("#columnHeaders > tbody > tr:gt(0)").each(function(i,e){
    var rowIndex = i + 1;//we skip the first row - which is used to initialize the array indexInfo
    var startColumnIndex = -1;
    $(this).find("th").each(function(j){
            startColumnIndex++;
            //if the current row is still in 'rowspan' range of the previous
            //row, we need to increase the column index
            while(indexInfo[startColumnIndex].rowSpan > rowIndex)
               startColumnIndex++;
            var rsa = $(this).attr("rowspan");
            var rs = rsa == undefined ? 1 : parseInt(rsa);
            var cia = $(this).data("column-index");
            var ci = cia == undefined ? -1 : parseInt(cia);
            //update the info
            indexInfo[startColumnIndex].rowSpan = rowIndex + rs;
            indexInfo[startColumnIndex].colIndex = ci;
    });
});
```

After having the correct info in a prepared array. You can just need to loop through all the `button`s in each `td` in the second table to set the `data-column-index` accordingly, something like this:

```
$("#kanban_rows > tbody > tr").each(function(i){
  $(this).find("td > button").each(function(j){
         $(this).attr("data-column-index", indexInfo[j].colIndex);
      });
});
```

And here is the updated demo (adjusted from your own demo):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qky4zx2o/2/)

You can inspect the page to see that the `data-column-index`s are added correctly (per your requirement).

Comment: Pretty neat. Thank you so much!

Comment: @herondale you're welcome, btw - I've just edited the answer a bit (in the second snippet - at line `indexInfo[startColumnIndex].rowSpan = ...`

Comment: oh, okay. :) By the way, I realized I'm a little confused here, what are `var startIndex = indexInfo.length;` and  `var endIndex = startIndex + cs;` exactly for? I don't think I'm quite sure

Comment: @herondale because of `colspan` the index of `indexInfo` does not match with the index of the `th` elements we loop through (if all `colspan` is 1, then they match). So `startIndex` here is just a running index of the `indexInfo` (which is independent from the index of `th` elements). We need that running index to ***build up*** the `indexInfo` array increasingly. You can see that when `colspan` is used, in fact there are a number ***virtual columns*** matching that `colspan` value. So we add `+cs` to loop through that range and init the virtual columns accordingly (as elements of `indexInfo`

Comment: ahh, i see, virtual columns. One more thing: `indexInfo[startColumnIndex].rowSpan = rowIndex + rs;` why do we need t o add the `rowIndex` and `rs` and set that as the new `rowspan` of that header?

Comment: the `rowspan` here is actually the maximum (upper bound) of the index. At the second header row, it's not important. But if you have more than 2 header rows (in your example you have just 2), then it's important. It's used to check if the looped header rows are in ***rowspan*** range of the previous header rows. It's a bit hard to explain, but I hope you can think of it more carefully, don't concentrate much on the naming.

Comment: yeah was just confirming cause i did think it was not necessary for the example i gave and wondered if you were just trying to cover other scenarios. I'm working it out right now on paper one by one, hopefully you'll be around should I have any other questions :)

Comment: Once you understand the idea, the code will not be hard. If you have any question related to this answer, I'll try to explain more. But if it's not much related, it's better to ask in another question (create new question) for other users to join in.

Comment: Can you check this out? I'm getting an error: `cannot read property 'colIndex' of undefined`. I played around with it a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/7mavkp6r/ @Hopeless

Comment: never mind, it was because of the excess button at the end. :)